# I want search the some partial Text in Excel

Tags: excel

I have some data which shown in the below image.

[image]

i want search the "B" cell data with "A" cell(B is some partial position name of A Cell)if it's match output will be Ok else Not

Comment: from your picture it's not clear what you need. Add another example with desired output

Answer (score 0):

I cannot view your example but i think this is what your looking for.
`=if(FIND("Something",A1),"TRUE","FALSE")` 
So what this function does is that it finds the word `Something` from A1 and if its equal to true it will return true else false.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/find-findb-HP005209089.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You will actually need to include an ISERROR condition in the if statement mentioned above, otherwise if the string does not exist, the return value will be "#VALUE"

Something more like this:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("Something", A1)), FALSE, TRUE)
```

Also note that FALSE and TRUE are logicals and do not need to be stated as strings. It's also unclear whether you are planning to search the entire array each time to determine whether a single value exists anywhere within, or whether you want to know at what positions the value appears, etc.